# Catch/Handle MySQL Duplicate Entry Error - with NodeJS, PassportJS, Express, connect-flash, Heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, passport.js, connect-flash

I am doing user registration for a node app, starting from [this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) example, but using a MySQL database instead of MongoDB. Multiple columns in the **users** table have a uniqueness constraint.

Here is the SQL code that creates the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `' + dbconfig.database + '`.`' + dbconfig.users_table + '` ( \
    `id`                  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT, \
    `username`            VARCHAR(60)  NULL, \
    `password`            CHAR(60)     NULL, \
    `facebook_id`         VARCHAR(60)  NULL, \
    `facebook_token`      CHAR(223)    NULL, \
    `facebook_name`       VARCHAR(100) NULL, \
    `facebook_email`      VARCHAR(100) NULL, \
    `google_id`           VARCHAR(60)  NULL, \
    `google_token`        CHAR(67)     NULL, \
    `google_name`         VARCHAR(100) NULL, \
    `google_email`        VARCHAR(100) NULL, \
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), \
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC), \
    UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC), \
    UNIQUE INDEX `facebook_id_UNIQUE` (`facebook_id` ASC), \
    UNIQUE INDEX `facebook_token_UNIQUE` (`facebook_token` ASC), \
    UNIQUE INDEX `google_id_UNIQUE` (`google_id` ASC), \
    UNIQUE INDEX `google_token_UNIQUE` (`google_token` ASC) \
)');
```

When the user is on their profile page and attempts to update the **facebook_id** in their existing user record, the update may violate the uniqueness constraint -- i.e. another user record already has that **facebook_id**.

The MySQL error message reflected in the Heroku log is:

```
Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' for key 'facebook_id_UNIQUE'
```

(I have substituted x's for the actual facebook_id.)

I want to do nothing except return to the page the user is already on (their profile page) and display an error message, "Facebook ID registered to another user." I am attempting to use the [connect-flash](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-flash) module to display the message. This is working in other places in the program.

I am attempting to accomplish this as follows:

```
if (err) {
    console.log("mylog : facebook connect error");
    if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
        //handle disconnect
    } else if (err.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
        console.log("mylog : fb ER_DUP_ENTRY detected");
        // release connection created with pool.getConnection
        if (connection) connection.release();
        // req.flash to set flashdata using connect-flash
        return done(err, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Facebook ID registered to another user.')); 
    } else { //continue }
```

On the profile.ejs page, I have the following:

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>
```

This code is working on the other .ejs pages.

In the case of the ER_DUP_ENTRY error, both console.log statements shown above are registering, so the program is detecting the ER_DUP_ENTRY error successfully, but instead of returning to the profile.ejs page as I hoped, the profile page disappears and and a lot of text is displayed in the browser, starting with:

```
Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' for key 'facebook_id_UNIQUE' at Query.Sequence._packetToError
```

The app doesn't crash, the user can still enter the home page URL in the browser and things are working as usual.

Any idea what is going wrong?  How can I handle this error so that the user just sees the connect-flash message on the profile page?

Answer (score 8):

maybe its 3 years late but I'm leaving the answer, better late than never!.

```
   if(err){  //we make sure theres an error (error obj)

        if(err.errno==1062){   
        req.flash('message','The entry already exist.'); //we send the flash msg
        return res.redirect('/admin/userPanel');
        db.end();
        }
        else{
            throw err;
        db.end();
        }
}
```

errorno is the property that you are looking for,  I got it when I printed err to console using console.log(err).

Here you can check all the errors number https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html

it was a pleasure! Good luck to the next good soul that read this.

Answer (score 3):

pretty straight and clear solution:
//----------------

```
connection.query('write your mysql query', function(err,rows){
      if(err)
      {

        if(err.code == 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' || err.errno == 1062)
        {
            console.log('Here you can handle duplication')
        }
        else{
           console.log('Other error in the query')
        }

      }else{
         console.log('No error in the query')
      }
 })
```